# JavaScript Spawn: How to pass variable to FLAG in Spawn python script

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, spawn

I have a python script which has two FLAGs `--server` and `--image`.

For now, in JavaScript, I can only assign the fixed value to FLAGS using spawn. For example: (This does yield the output)

```
var pyProg = spawn('python', ['./MLmodel/inception_client.py', '--server=30.220.240.190:9000', '--image=./testImage/DSC00917.JPG']);

pyProg.stdout.on('data', function (data) { console.log('This is result ' + data.toString());});
```

However, I want to assign a string variable and pass the string to the FLAG. For example: (This is wrong, it does not yield any output)

```
var imagePath = './testImage/DSC00917.JPG'

var pyProg = spawn('python', ['./MLmodel/inception_client.py', '--server=30.220.240.190:9000', '--image=imagePath']);

pyProg.stdout.on('data', function (data) { console.log('This is result ' + data.toString());});
```

How should I make it work? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use string concatenation as you would anywhere else in JavaScript.
If you would want `console.log` to print a variable you would do it like this:

```
console.log('image path is ' + imagePath);
```

or if you are using ES6 string interpolation:

```
console.log(`image path is ${imagePath}`);
```

The same works for your code example:

```
var imagePath = './testImage/DSC00917.JPG'
var pyProg = spawn('python', ['./MLmodel/inception_client.py', '--server=30.220.240.190:9000', '--image=' + imagePath]);
```

Comment: WOW! I never knew that! Thank you so much for helping me! Really appreciate and it works!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mark as accepted. Here you are! Thanks! @geekonaut